# Not getting error prompt in semantic ui form validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic ui. I have a modal and a form inside it. The issue is I'm not getting the invalid email error prompt. When an invalid email address is entered the field becomes red which means the error is being caught but I'm not getting error prompt. Please tell me where I'm wrong. I'd also like to know what the "identifier" option is all about.

HTML

```
  <div class="ui basic modal" id="qqmodal">
      <i class="close icon"></i>

    <div class="ui compact raised segment" id="qqform">
<form class="ui form" action="qqsend.php" method="post">

        <div class="field"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" id="qqname"></div>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" autocomplete="off" id="qqphone"></div>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off"></div>
        <h5 class="ui header">What do you want?</h5>
        <div class="inline field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb1">
          <label>New Website</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inline field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb2">
          <label>Website Redesign</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inline field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb3">
          <label>Search Engine Optimization</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inline field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb4">
          <label>Mobile App</label>
        </div>
        </div>


      <div class="field">
      <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Describe your requirements" name="description" id="desc"></textarea>

        </div>

        <center><button type="submit" class="ui blue button" id="smbtn">Submit</button></center>
</form>
</div>

  </div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#qqform form').form(
{
on: 'blur',
fields: {

  mail: {
    identifier  : 'mail',
    rules: [
       {
        type   : 'email',
        prompt : 'Please enter a valid e-mail'
       }
     ]
   }
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 7):

To have the prompt appear, add `inline: true` as an option on your `.form()` call.

If you'd prefer to group the prompts instead, add a `<div class="ui error message"></div>` to your markup, but omit the `inline` option or set it to false.

**Example**

```js
$('#qqform form').form({
  on: 'blur',
  inline: true,
  fields: {
    mail: {
      identifier: 'mail',
      rules: [{
        type: 'email',
        prompt: 'Please enter a valid e-mail'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui compact raised segment" id="qqform">
  <form class="ui form" action="qqsend.php" method="post">

    <div class="field">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" id="qqname">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" autocomplete="off" id="qqphone">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <h5 class="ui header">What do you want?</h5>
    <div class="inline field">
      <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb1">
        <label>New Website</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline field">
      <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb2">
        <label>Website Redesign</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline field">
      <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb3">
        <label>Search Engine Optimization</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline field">
      <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="servicecb4">
        <label>Mobile App</label>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
      <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Describe your requirements" name="description" id="desc"></textarea>

    </div>
    
    <div class="ui error message"></div>

    <center>
      <button type="submit" class="ui blue button" id="smbtn">Submit</button>
    </center>
    
  </form>
</div>

</div>
```

The `identifier` is defined as follows:

> A validation object includes a list of form elements, and rules to validate each field against. Fields are matched by either the `id`, `name`, or `data-validate` property matching the identifier specified in the settings object.

Source: [Form Validation - Specifying Validation Rules](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#specifying-validation-rules)